# password algorithm hash_algos overkill

Tags: php, security, hash, md5, salt

Just curious in the speed and productivity and the security in using all hash_algos

```
Array
 (
   [0] => md2
   [1] => md4
   [2] => md5
   [3] => sha1
   [4] => sha224
   [5] => sha256
   [6] => sha384
   [7] => sha512
   [8] => ripemd128
   [9] => ripemd160
   [10] => ripemd256
   [11] => ripemd320
   [12] => whirlpool
   [13] => tiger128,3
   [14] => tiger160,3
   [15] => tiger192,3
   [16] => tiger128,4
   [17] => tiger160,4
   [18] => tiger192,4
   [19] => snefru
   [20] => snefru256
   [21] => gost
   [22] => adler32
   [23] => crc32
   [24] => crc32b
   [25] => salsa10
   [26] => salsa20
   [27] => haval128,3
   [28] => haval160,3
   [29] => haval192,3
   [30] => haval224,3
   [31] => haval256,3
   [32] => haval128,4
   [33] => haval160,4
   [34] => haval192,4
   [35] => haval224,4
   [36] => haval256,4
   [37] => haval128,5
   [38] => haval160,5
   [39] => haval192,5
   [40] => haval224,5
   [41] => haval256,5
)
```

Obviously this would be overkill yet strictly speaking from a whim and wonderment would looping these methods with our password and salts and then using our return saying `md5` being our last algorithm to be ran as the store. How long would it be to crack the said password? As ive read in some documentation  `with a password 8 or less characters in length it takes only 6 hours to crack` so in reference if our stipulations and regulations to a password was

One uppercase letter
Two numbers
And no less than 10 characters in length

Then loop our password in the hash_algs essentially our password could nearly be unbreakable though I shouldn't use that since everything these days is able to be cracked.

So my concerns are is this feasible
Will it have a heavy page load
Regulations to passwords strength stronger like this
Is it truly overkill or is it like fort knox security?

Comment: https://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/115406/is-it-more-secure-to-hash-a-password-multiple-times

Comment: So by using different algorithms your actually weakening its strength? That is what I am getting from that article.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mixing all hash functions is not a good idea, because they are still too fast and you don't know if they influence each other.

An appropriate password hash function should be **slow** (need some computing time). If an attacker tries to crack passwords, and the hashing was properly handled, the only way for him is brute-forcing, usually done in combination with a dictionary.

That means, the more passwords he can try per second, the faster he will find the original password. Today you can for example calculate about [8 Giga MD5 hashes per second](http://hashcat.net/oclhashcat/#performance) with common hardware.

There are algorithms like BCrypt and PBKDF2 with a cost factor, you can use the PHP function [password_hash()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) to generate a BCrypt hash. The cost factor defines how many times the hash function is iterated, so you can control how much time the calculation of one try needs. A millisecond to gain access to your website is not much, a millisecond to brute-force is a stopper. With your chaining of hashes you still have only 40 fast calculations.

If your are interested in more information about password storing, you could have a look at my [tutorial](http://www.martinstoeckli.ch/hash/en/index.php) about secure password storing.

Comment: Well it seems like you know what you're doing and I don't mind reading, just don't of the official documentation is all over the place and then gets tiring to read.

Answer (score 1):

Using all of the algorithms is complete overkill. If I were you, just generate a random salt for each user (possibly by MD5 hashing uniqid, just an example), and hash the password with said salt. Blowfish encryption will work great for you.

Comment: Since I am fairly new can you explain blowfish to me please. And I was actually just thinking about generating a unique salt with id as well haha